# MVVM Store State in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am using MVVM with WPF, but I am having a hard time understanding the concepts behind this desing pattern.

I have a "myclass" object that is the state of the application (it stores data loaded from the repository). All pages of my application will use this data and the object should be syncronized between them all.

My first approach was to store this data in the service layer, using a singleton class. So, all ViewModel should call this service to get the data. Any modification should also call this service, and a event would be fired to synchronize all views.

I am wondering now if it would be better to store this data in the model layer...
What's be best option?

EDIT:
Adding more information:
The data stored is a list of projects loaded into a solution. Since there must be only one solution, I implemented it as a singleton. The must can interactively load, change, or remove any project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service to my understanding is just something that abstracts a piece of functionality(access the file-system, access a database...) which say implements a given interface that the `VM`'s can then use when requiring that functionality.

A Model however **holds** the business logic of your application and anything that will assist performing that business logic (which can / cannot implement [INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if desired)

So in essence you use a service to get something done and let go of it, a Model is more ingrained to your application

For your given use-case, I'd have the stored info in the Model and implement `INPC` on it so that the ViewModels get notified of changes automatically if another ViewModel makes a change to the Model.